# Как использовать многопоточность для одной функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Это достаточно простенький вопрос, мне интересно могу ли я использовать многопоточность без лямда функций и что бы это смотрелась хорошо.

Сейчас я использую это так

```
thread th([&]()
            {
                folderAPI(a, b, c);
            });
        th.detach();

thread th2([&]() { TestfolderAPI(test_a, test_b, test_c); }); th2.join();
```

Вроде выглядит ничего, нормально, но этот код занимает очень много строк, а если сделать все в одну строку, то становится не понятно.

На данный момент я ничего не добавляю кроме одной функции или одного класса в один поток.

Comment: `thread` принимает в качестве первого аргумента любую [вызываемую](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) сущность. Это может быть и указатель на обычную функцию: `thread t(&foo)`, где `foo` - функция

Comment: @acade попробовал чет не получается у меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать передачу аргументов вызываемой функции непосредственно в конструктор therad:

```
std::thread th( &folderAPI, std::ref(a), std::ref(b), std::ref(c) );
```

`std::ref` здесь означает передачу аргументов по ссылке. (Без него будет передача по значению, т.е. копирование.)
Но не уверен, что это читабельнее.

Для борьбы с большим числом аргументов функции можно, например, группировать их в структуры.

Comment: А где `th.join();` или `th.detach();` или это реально не обязательно?

Comment: Обязательно, конечно. Просто хотелось выделить часть которая собственно, вызывает сложность чтения.

Comment: А можно пример без ref я пытаюсь сделать тоже самое у меня ошибка)
это выглядит читабельней чем с лямдой

Comment: Без ref все тоже самое, только без ref: `std::thread th( &folderAPI, a, b, c );` Но, это уже другое поведение, поскольку в оригинальной лямбде было указано сохранять переменные именно по ссылке.

Comment: кажется без `ref()` не работает вообще, только с `ref`, но из-за нее сильно читабельность падает.

Comment: Ладно пойдет, спс.

Comment: @badbi интересно, что по вашему: из-за нее читабельность падает? Вы вообще понимаете, что делает эта функция и зачем она нужна?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я оставил лямда решения пока что, лучше наверно нету.

Comment: @badbi а по каким критериям вы сравнивает? С лямбдой вы используете дополнительный объект.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я сравниваю только по удобству, мне не важно дольше будет работать или нет, главное чистый код и что бы можно было максимально быстро понять, за полиномиальное время.

Comment: @badbi это хорошо, что вы такие слова знаете, как "полиномиальное" - дела за малым: понять что это означает и когда его употреблять)))

Answer (score 1):

Тут все просто: необязательно использовать std::thread,  есть еще async(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) или openMP(https://www.openmp.org/).

Теперь к std::thread:
При использовании потоков Вам все равно приходиться учитывать возвращаемое значение или exception. С этим отлично справляется std::packaged_task (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

Вот Вам минимальный пример :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>


namespace test {
    std::mutex mtx;

    void __attribute__((noinline))
    foo(uint64_t& a) {
            {
               std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul{mtx};
                --a;
            }
        // для примера
        throw std::runtime_error("bla bla bla");
    }
}

int main() {
    std::packaged_task<void(uint64_t&)> xTask(test::foo);
    auto task = xTask.get_future();
    uint64_t a{1};
    std::thread th{std::move(xTask), std::ref(a)};
    /* * @brief исключительно ради примера
       *        ибо зачем ждать поток после его инициализации????
       */
    if (th.joinable()) {
        th.join();
    }

    try {
        task.wait();
        // чтобы поймать исключение
        task.get();
        return static_cast<int>(a);
    } catch (std::runtime_error& err) {
        std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "unknown error ~ !"<< std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    return -3;
}
```

Как сюда запихнуть анонимную функцию вы уже наверно догадались )

Comment: Из вашего кода меня больше заинтересовала функция исключения, типа перехват ошибок из потока, как это работает?
она перехватывает прямо внутри вызывающей функции или только поверхностно?
Просто я обычно исключения добавляю внутри функции, но если я добавлю исключения поверх потока как у вас, будет ли это работать.
И если да то это очень интересно.

Comment: соберите код с -pthread  и попробуйте использовать gdb (пройтись по коду)  с установкой сигнала и все поймете

Comment: Ваш код очень сложный для понимания, я не могу его добавить к себе, если конечно переделать возможно, но нужно для этого перерыть куча примеров с похожей реализацией что бы оптимизировать хоть как то.

Comment: Постарайтесь разобраться или почитайте литератору по многопоточному программированию на C++, в любом случае умение разбираться в чужом коде необходимо

Comment: Мне не сложно разобраться в таком коде, мне сложно его поддерживать.

Comment: Это просто банальный пример - Ваша реализация - это Ваша реализация